# transformation matrices and complex functions as projections

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra, functions, complex-analysis, math-software

This question is about the connection between linear algebra and complex analysis. Coming from a two real dimensional domain a transformation matrix geometrically transforms a set of points (e.g. a circle) in that plane to another set of points in the two real dimensional codomain. The same holds true for a complex valued function which does the transformation from a one complex dimensional domain to the complex dimensional codomain.

**I have two questions:** 

1. Do you know of any software (or add-ons) that let you "paint" some images and have them transformed by an arbitrary transformation matrix and/or complex function? 
2. What is the connection between transformation matrices and complex functions? How can you get from one to the other, i.e. finding corresponding transformation matrices to a given complex function and vice versa to produce the same transformation on the plane?

Any answers concerning the above questions will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: [Geometer's Sketchpad 5](http://www.keypress.com/x24070.xml) can probably apply almost any transformation (or complex function that can be used as a transformation) to an arbitrary image, including a hand-drawn one, but it's not necessarily a simple thing to achieve in Sketchpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For complex functions, try [Bombelli](http://www.dmat.ufpe.br/~ssc/bombelli/) or [Complex visualizer](http://www.saunalahti.fi/mattpaa/complex/complex.html) (both are Java applets).
2. In general, there is no connection. Transformation matrices correspond to *linear* mappings, and complex functions are in general *nonlinear*. Exception: the function $f(z)=(a+ib)z$ which simply multiplies $z$ by the constant $a+ib$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real) corresponds to the linear transformation given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$.

(Close to a point $z_0$ where $f'(z_0) \neq 0$, the formula $f(z)-f(z_0) \approx f'(z_0) (z-a)$ shows that the function $f$ can be approximated using a linear function of the above type, but that's a different story.)